# Monitoring OpenShift origin

Tags: openshift-origin, cockpit

How do we go about monitoring the cluster on the OpenShift origin? Some references around cockpit exists on the web, but seems it's only an option for OpenShift Enterprise. Can anyone please clarify if cockpit can be installed on OpenShift origin and used to monitor the services deployed?
Also if the Cockpit is not an option for OpenShift Origin, which particular solution is recommended for monitoring OpenShift Origin?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cockpit is available in a variety of distributions

- Fedora, Red Hat, and CentOS include it
- Debian and Ubuntu have repo access to install

See the Cockpit project here:
http://cockpit-project.org/running.html

That said, Cockpit does more to provide visibility one-host at a time.  When Red Hat packages the Enterprise version of OpenShift they also include the equivalent of ManageIQ to provide more holistic visibility and reporting capability.  Look at ManageIQ and "containers providers"

Finally, here's a link to a recent presentation on using ManageIQ for both OpenShift and Kubernetes management.  I recall it had some practical examples for how to implement.
http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Managing%20Kubernetes%20with%20ManageIQ%20ContainerCon%20final.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the latest version of ManageIQ include Cockpit integration, so you can have both under the same interface...